# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 8.86 GiB for an array with shape (1189469420,) and data type int64

Tags: python, memory, anaconda, out-of-memory

I have Windows10 / 64bit and running the code on Anaconda

I've tried to run a code of fuzzymatch with two datas one of 19343 rows × 24 columns and the other one of 501428 rows × 30 columns and here is the code:

```
matched_results = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(cenagro_names,
                                           pett_names,
                                           left_on,
                                           right_on,
                                           left_id_col = 'P003',
                                           right_id_col = 'ID_DIST')
```

and the memory error appears after about 10 min:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 8.86 GiB for an array with shape (1189469420,) and data type int64
```

On the Anaconda enviroment it says that the python version is 3.7.7 but I don't know how to notice is Python is 32bit or 64bit, I mention the latter since I´ve read that sometimes this error occurs because Python is 32bit and the OS is 64bit or viceversa.
I appreciate any possible answers!

Edit:
So I´ve tried 
`import struct
print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)` 
and it returns 64 meaning python is running 64bit, then what would be the problem now about the memory error?

Comment: I can't tell from your question...is there any chance it just legitimately can't allocate that much memory? It's quite a bit.

Comment: @DanGetz I don't really know, I´m quite new on this enviroment so I don´t know if there´s a way to tell if what you say is what´s happening and specially I don´t know how to solve it.

Comment: On Windows, you should be able to find out how much free memory you have by pressing the Ctrl-Alt-Del combination and choosing "Task Manager", then the Performance tab.

Comment: @DanGetz I have 332GB free in C: (where the ipynb file is running)

Comment: that's not the same kind of memory. The "memory" in `MemoryError` means RAM.

Comment: @DanGetz my laptop has for RAM 8GB with 5GB usable left

Comment: OK, well there it is. Python is saying it's trying to allocate something 8.86 GiB of size in your RAM, which is too small for that. That's what the error message means. I imagine it's trying to allocate a lot of memory because your dataframes are so big. I took a look at the project site for `fuzzymatcher` but don't see any mention of ways to use less memory. I wonder, is there any way you could achieve your same goal by splitting your datasets into parts, doing fuzzy matching on the parts, and combining later?

Comment: @DanGetz oh ok thanks a lot, I will try it

Comment: So, I've figured I can't do that since two blocks of the data can be related and might be a matched that could not be recognized if I slipt it. @DanGetz